# increment specific elements of array with intrinsics

Tags: c++, intrinsics

I am using c++. I have 2 arrays of short elements. First with values, second with indexes of the first array which should be increment. I have code like this:

```
const int N1=...;
const int N2=...;
int arr1[N1];
int arr2[N2];
....
for (int i = 0;i<N2;i++)
    arr1[arr2[i]]++;
```

I want to optimize this this code for time. I thought to use intrinsics. Is it possible to use intrinsics for this and how.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try to parallelize it using [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with [`std::execution::parallel_policy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par,
              arr2,
              arr2 + N2,
              [arr1](int i){ arr1[i]++; });
```

Note that this would require access to a C++17 enabled compiler.

Comment: Be careful though: if values in `arr2` are not unique, this code exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.